# How to save position of reordered cells in Collection View after I restart the app? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When I am trying to reorder position of cells in UICollectionView  using these two methods:

```
var teams: [Team]?

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let temp = teams?[sourceIndexPath.item] {
        teams?[sourceIndexPath.item] = (teams?[destinationIndexPath.item])!
        teams?[destinationIndexPath.item] = temp
    }

    print("Starting Index: \(sourceIndexPath.item)")
    print("Ending Index: \(destinationIndexPath.item)")
}
```

It works fine however after restarting my app I want to save position of reordered cells.

Which approach could you recommend me?

Additional info:

The Array of "teams" is storing objects of class Team:

```
class Team: NSObject {

    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var logo: String?
    var players: [Player]?
}

class Player: NSObject {

    var alias: String?
    var name: String?
    var age: String?
    var country: String?
    var imageName: String?
    var info: Info?
}

class Info: NSObject {

    var screenshots: [String]?
    var bio: String?
    var gear: Gear?
    var povs: [String]?
    var cfg: Config?
}

class Gear: NSObject {

    var monitor: String?
    var mouse: String?
    var mousepad: String?
    var keyboard: String?
    var headset: String?
}

class Config: NSObject {

    var mouseSettings: [String]?
    var monitorSettings: [String]?
    var crosshaircfg: [String]?
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I guess you can use core data for this purpose, when you restart your app , get the reordered records from coredata and display on the screen

Comment: You should save the unique identifier for your cell not its order such as `team.id`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use UserDefaults for this.

I stored the position as an integer in the userDefaults and used the item name as the key.

> How to store the positions

```
func saveReorderedArray() {
    for (index, item) in yourArray.enumerated() {
        let position = index + 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(position, forKey: item.name)
    }
}
```

And upon application launch I called reorderArray function to grab the positions and stored it in a array of dictionaries using the item names as the keys.

> How to retreive the positions

```
func reorderArray() {
    var items: [[String: Int]] = []

    // Get the positions
    for item in yourArray {
        var position = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: item.name)

        // If a new item is added, set position to 999
        if position == 0 {
            position = 999
        }

        items.append([itemName : position])
    }

    for item in items {
        // Get position from dictionary
        let position = Array(item.values)[0]
        let itemName = Array(item.keys)[0]

        // Get index from yourArray
        let index = yourArray.index { (item) -> Bool in
            item.name == itemName
        }

        // Arrange the correct positions for the cells
        if let i = index {
            let m = yourArray.remove(at: i)

            // Append to last position of the array
            if position == 999 {
                yourArray.append(m)
            } 
            else {
                yourArray.insert(m, at: position - 1)  // Insert at the specific position
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helped!